# PayPal Express redirects to main site before payment is completed

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, redirect, paypal-express, magento-1.9.3.2

Been having some problems with PayPal checkout on my site.

Customers are able to confirm the order in Magento, proceed to PayPal, check order details, but when they click continue - at that point they are redirected back to the main page of the site before actually being able to send payment.

I'm not sure where the problem is at or where to go from here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you any error message?, any trace? what version of Magento are you using?.

Comment: No error message or anything, just a straight redirect. Unfortunately I can't actually test the problem myself as I don't have a separate PayPal account to test with, so I am just relying on what customers are telling me.

Magento ver. 1.9.3.2

Comment: Are you using PayPal Express, PayPal Standard?, By your comment I understand it redirects to `Home` Page isn't?

Comment: PayPal Express.

Comment: PayPal Express automatically redirects to a page called Order Confirmation Page. is that the case? or is it actually redirecting to the `home` page?

Comment: Customers fill out all information on my website and go through the entire checkout process. At the end when they choose to pay with PayPal, they are redirected to PayPal where they are able to verify the order, but when they press 'continue' to send payment, they are redirected to the store (my website), without payment having being sent, and without the order having been placed (no order emails / no order in dashboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you are describing it seems like your customers are been redirected to a page called *Order Confirmation Page*.

PayPal Express is designed to work this way (redirect to Paypal, then redirect to your website again). One reason is for example, that your business terms etc. must be shown to the customer before he finally agrees to buy.

If this is case, have a look to the PayPal configuration in the admin panel, and look for an option called `Skip Order Review Step`, make sure is set to `Yes`.